# How to replace an online folder by local folder using Fiddler?

Tags: regex, fiddler

I'm struggling to make my browser fetch all files from local folder instead of all files from target online folder.
I want to achieve it using Telerik Fiddler (which has relevant AutoResponder feature).
As I understood, I should write corresponding regular expressions for target online folder and for local folder as well. But I can't figure out how they should look.
In another proxy debugger, Charles Proxy, it would be basically this easy:

```
location: http://examplesite.com/target_folder/*
local path: c:\local_folder
```

Same approach didn't work in Fiddler for me. Then I've found some [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/BWfUoCuih8k) by Eric Lawrence, but either it is irrelevant, or I'm applying it incorrect. Anyway it doesn't work for me too. I've tried something like this:

```
REGEX:^http://examplesite.com/target_folder/(.+)$
REGEX:C:\local_folder\$1
```

So, please, give me a hint, how regexps for replacing whole folder (online) to whole folder (local) should be written in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash in RegEx matches the next character literally, so your response RegEx redirects to something like `C:local_folder$1`. If you remove the 'REGEX:' from the response, it should work in case of one response, or escape the backslashes in your case:

- Match: `REGEX:^http://examplesite.com/target_folder/(.+)$`
- Response: `REGEX:C:\\local_folder\\$1`

However, there are all sorts of restrictions for running local file content in most browsers. If this is used for anything other than static content, I recommend installing a local web server which you can use for the auto-responder.